# VSCode changes permission from 664 to 644 (and 775 to 755)

Tags: visual-studio-code, debian, privileges

We have this problem using VSCode:

- creating files using either GUI or console with VSCode gives them permission 644 (on directory it is 755)
- creating files using Putty and by Windows CMD gives required permission 664 (and 775)
  Considering this it seems like the problem is connected to VSCode and not the Linux settings.

We are using „Remote Development” extension (Remote – Containers / SSH / SSH: Editing Configuration Files / WSL also installed) to do this with VSCode.

System where the files are created:
Debian 9.12
Shell: bash 4.4.12

System where the VSCode is run:
Windows 10
version 1903

We have tried setting umask, but nothing changes.

Comment: Probably you need to configure wsl properly in your debian and enable metadata and umask there. This link may help, https://gist.github.com/roustem/2702553a5baa21bd3abd1becf951445b#wsl-setup

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
my friend found the solution (thank you too Abdullah Al Farooq - it was good starting point to where to look for - WSL indeed was the problem):

Solution:

- run PowerShell (as admin)
- type: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
- restart system

This worked on two machines.
Link:
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001879.htm

For me - it still was not working at this point. I had to make "clean instal" on VSCode because the umask was still setting to default 0022 every time.

Link:
https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/visual-studio-code/remove-vs-code-completely.html

After that - it works perfectly.